# Change Product Specification Price on Product Attribute selection change

Tags: c#, .net, e-commerce, nopcommerce

I am using Nopcommerce I want to do whenever any attribute is changed or selection of attribute changes then product specification values also changes
Like if we have a jewellery product that has following specifications -

GOld - 5000
Diamond -9000
Making charges - 1200
Tax - 569

then on changing of like product attribute from 14k to 28k then Amount of gold also increases so it automatically updates the value of GOld from 5000 to suppose 8000 or something else

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a similar pattern of `Observer Pattern`.
.Net language already support what you are looking for through the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface

You can find some details about how to implement [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You can trigger multitude of actions upon receiving an event of a specific property that has changed.

Comment: I am using Nopcommerce

Comment: In nopcommerce 3.4 mvc version product price can be changed depending upon attribute selection i want to do same like updating Product specification change on attribute selection